# Angular 10 JWT asp.net core display user online status realtime

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, jwt

Im using angular 10 as my frontend and asp.net core as my backend.
I use jwt as my user authentication method.
User posts its username and password to the server side and server generates a token sending it back to the user. And I save the token in user's browser local storage.
I have written an http interceptor which adds authorization bearer to the header section of user's api requests.
This is the way server knows who is who.
Now I have a page in which I should display online and offline users with green and red dots next to their names.
I can know when a user signs in because it has to login and I can do whateverI want when user signs in but I dont know how to let my client know when users close their browser and leave the site.
I am looking for any library, logic or anything to know my user's online/offline status realtime.
I should display which users are online and which are not and it should be realtime.
I use microsoft identity context to handle membership.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.
I need to add that I want a solution rather than code. I just want to know how to do it. I can handle the code work myself. I just want to know how?

Comment: I think a more reliable solution for this would have to use SignalR. Handling edge cases like a user being connected in multiple devices at the same time would probably not work well with a REST API.

Comment: SignalR has completely different model of scalability and should only be used together with deep understanding of what actually happens.

Comment: Mateus thanks for your comment. The main problem is when user leaves the web page nothing is triggered and backend can't understand when user gets offline.

Comment: @wiktor zychla can you draw a scenario like very simple one? Should I use signalR?

Comment: @Ali.Rashidi: you could register an exact date/time of last user API call. Then your "who's online" list would rather be a list of "who made a call in last X minutes" (like 5). This is an approximation (someone could have made a request and just quit). If you want better, SignalR could be a way but be aware of its server-side requirements.

Comment: @wiktor Zychla If I am to register a datetime in every single api call to the server, then don't you think it would be a high load for my server? And what it is that makes you worried about signalR? You're kinda suggesting not to use it, aren't you?

Comment: @WiktorZychla I agree that SignalR should be it's own separate web app with connection based scaling. So, unless you're using Azure and their SignalR scaling service, this might be an overkill for this feature.

Comment: Another option would be to make a lightweight hearbeat HTTP request every few minutes, for example, that would update a "LastOnline" date in the database or cache/memory, which would then be queried by the who's online page. It would be more precise then looking for "who made any call in last X minutes" but would somewhat increase the load on the API server.

Comment: @Ali.Rashidi: no, I am not suggesting SignalR. SignalR means an open socket connection from the client which means a single server accepts just few thousand connections until it runs out of free slots to accept clients. A regular web app doesn't have this limitation as the connection can be closed when new clients request resources (single server can easily handle millions of users in a regular request-reply app). So use SignalR only if you know what you are doing and you can scale it horizontally.

Comment: @MateusSchneiders: the "heartbeat endpoint but extra calls" is another valid option. If there's no pressure on live reporting, this can be not that bad as it sounds in terms of the extra load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a web application to know live information about other users sessions will require the server to publish the other user's data in some way.

One approach would be to use a framework to handle server initiate communication via [websockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#Browser_implementation). This would require something like [SignalR](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/main/src/SignalR), for your ASP.NET Core application, for your server to **push** the user changes.
Using websockets is not hard, but it comes with a steep learning curve and more server requirements to attend to.

As Second approach would be to periodically **pull** the information about the other users (someone called it "hearbeat request" on the question comments).
In this approach you create a normal endpoint on your app, and have your front-end page periodically call it to update the user's info.
This is much simpler then websockets to implement, and does not add requirements to your current infrastructure.

The difference on the approaches is how close you get to real-time, and the effort to implement it.

- With websockets the server would push the user session changes as they occur, there cannot be more real-time then this.
- Without websockets the client would have to keep pulling the user changes, so in the time between pull's you loose some "real-time".